# c++ Algorithm: searching for a subset of a 'list', non-ordered

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

UPDATE: MY BAD. this was not the cause of the double slowdown. I had other bugs.

C++ MFC. Visual Studio 12.

I'm trying to optimize performance within a draw loop. I have a list of all my objects(ListAll), lets say it has 300 objects, all with unique ID's. I have a second list(ListNow) of the ID's which need to be rendered, size of 100. all the values in ListNow have associated objects stored in ListAll.

currently, ListAll is a CMap < UINT, UINT, Object*, Object*>, and ListNow is a CArray< UINT,UINT>.

```
// this is the slower, current method
for (int i = 0; i < ListNow.GetSize(); i++)
{
    UINT id = ListNow.GetAt(i);
    if (ListAll->Lookup(id, object))
    {
        object->draw();
    }
}
```

in the past I only had ListAll(CMap), and I called draw() on every object in it. It only had the 100 I wanted to draw, and I 'rebuilt' it every time i switched what was being drawn.

```
// this is the faster, old method
POSITION pos = ListAll->GetStartPosition();
while (pos)
{
    ListAll->GetNextAssoc(pos, id, object);
    object->Draw();
}
```

Technically both algorithms perform at O(n) speed...but simply adding the CMap::Lookup function to the loop has doubled the time it takes. I have properly set my CMap size to a prime number larger than the number of objects in the CMap. This slowdown is blatant with lists of size 300,000 and above.

I switched to this system so that I could store all the objects in the draw lists, and could quickly swap between what is being drawn between different windows using the same object lists. This speeds up time when switching drastically but has slowed down each individual draw call. Switching back now is not an option, we knew it would slow down each draw call a bit, but not this much. The slowdown is definitely in the code I show you, because when i switch back to drawing everything(remove the lookup), it cuts time in half.

My only idea to increase performance is to record the LastDrawn object pointers in a list, and inform the function if it needs to change(call lookup()) or if it can simply re-use the last drawn(GetNext()). since 90% of the time, nothing has changed between calls.

Does anyone have a faster solution than this? I'm dreaming of a tricky bit masking solution that somehow produces the object pointers i want, I don't know. Anything would help at this point.

Comment: Are you sure the slowdown is in CMap::lookup? Good hash map implementations should not slow you down with O(1) average complexity. If was profiled, and confirmed, try `std::unordered_map` Looked into `lookup`, signature, looks like it is copying data around? Ughhh.... You really should look into `unordered_map`.

Comment: About how many items in ListNow correspond to ListAll?

Comment: @SergeyA True, it is copying into the provided `rvalue`, but `GetNextAssoc` also does that for each member in the map in the second loop.

Comment: cocarin, anywhere from 1 to all. sergeyA, copying data? object is a pointer, so hopefully it is only copying that pointer, and the UINT id per Lookup. Are you saying there is more copying internally in the CMap class?

Comment: @diox8tony If you force `ListNow` to point to everything in `ListAll` do you still see the performance problem? This is pretty much equivalent to the second loop where you draw everything anyway, but uses the new looping semantics. Good test cases here would be (No items in `ListNow`, half of `ListAll` in `ListNow`, and all of `ListAll` in `ListNow`).

Comment: How do you generate the id's, are they sequential or random, and is there an initial starting value or do you start at 0?  CMap uses a hashing algorithm, so if your unique identifiers cause a large number of hash collisions, you might see the kind of slowdown you describe.  Also, can you put some real numbers on the speeds you have measured?  How many seconds/milliseconds/microseconds to redraw 100 out of 300 objects?  It may help get an idea of what kind of slowdown we're expecting, if it isn't a hash collision problem.

Comment: Could you not just add a simple boolean flag to the class of objects you store in `ListAll`? Iterating over all items to determine which ones need to be drawn is something you need to do anyway in one way or another; then, simply checking for the flag in your render loop should not be that expensive (unless `ListAll` is some orders of magnitude larger than `ListNow`).

Comment: Are you bottlenecking on cache misses or on CPU throughput, with big lists?  Your old method is iterating through the CMap in it's "natural" order, right?  So memory prefetching hardware can do its job and have the next element ready.  If `ListNow` results in scattered accesses into the hash table, that's bad.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you problem will be solved if you store your Object's pointers instead of their IDs into your `ListNow`.

Comment: wow. That's actually a really good idea. so simple. XD The system I'm working on is much more complex than this example, but this might be able to be implemented.